# Ruby package require libraries

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm new to Ruby - came from Java background.

I want to use third party library in my ruby app, but I do not wish to do `gem install xxx`. Is that possible? (In java, you add the third party library in your classpath to use it)

Comment: Many languages have their own way of including libraries. and to go against the established protocols for an language comes with a price. Its not rally helpfull to try do things in ruby as they are done in java. Learning such a different language as ruby (as compared to java) is more about unlearning things than learning new things :). any ways there is a way to do it if you really need to. check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same in Ruby.

```
require 'lib/yourlibrary.rb'
```

Or:

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path(File.dirname(FILE) + “/../lib”))
require 'yourlibrary.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

To include a gem in your project, you could download the module and place it in the same folder as your code and then do a 'require'. You can also download the module with Rubygems copy, or you can download the module from it's project page.